# Get a json from another tab or window

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, browser

I have two servers: one for html, the other as an API to connect to twitter.
On the HTML Server, I open a new tab (or window) to call my API that redirects to the twitter login page. Once finished, my API returns a JSON.
How can I get it back?
Is there a callback? Should I put it in cookies or localStorage? 
Any Solution with Ajax ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but it sounds like you're attempting to get the user to access their Twitter account and return that information to the first site. If so I'd suggest you look in to OAuth using the Twitter JS SDK

Comment: In other words, what I want is for the user to accept my application, once that is done, I record the data on my API, and I send the client a code that will allow him to use the twitter features

Answer (score 0):

I have no other solution than to put parameters in the twitter callback